# next/link redirect and should to scroll, it should directly positioning to top

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-link

I have next js web, which has some links to redirect on the footer,
so if I click on that link it is first redirected to that page with scrolled down(current position) and then scrolls the up
I don't want to scroll up, it should by default from the top of the page
any suggestions will be appreciated

```
<NextLink href="/news">
  <a onClick={() => trackClick("News")}>In the News</a>
</NextLink>
```

Comment: To clarify, do you want the page to scroll to the top after page navigation, or do you want the page to keep the current position?

Answer (score 0):

You can set scroll to false like this:

```
<NextLink href="/news" scroll={false}>
  <a onClick={() => trackClick("News")}>In the News</a>
</NextLink>
```

To automaticly scroll to the top without an animation, you have to add a useEffect either to _app.ts or on the specific pages:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  const { pathname } = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    // some browsers (like safari) may require a timeout to delay calling this
    // function after a page has loaded; otherwise, it may not update the position
    window.scrollTo(0, 0, behavior: 'instant');
  }, [pathname]);

  return <Component {...pageProps} />
};

export default App;
```